# update column_B of specific row that "xxx" is present

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't really know much at all about writing a script for sql and the guy who normally does it is off the next couple of weeks.

I need help trying to write a script that will change the value in a column called "UPDATE_FLAG" from false to true, wherever "xxx" is present. "xxx" could be in any column, but i need the value of the "UPDATE_FLAG" to only change in the specific row that "xxx" is present. Also there could be multiple rows with "xxx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide much specific information you'll only get a generalized answer:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET Update_Flag = 1            // this assumes the flag is an integer value
WHERE (column1 = "xxx")        // if it's a string do SET Update_Flag = "True"
OR (column2 = "xxx")
OR (column3 = "xxx")
```

etcetera...

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set update_flag=1
   where
      column1 = 'xxx' or
      column2 = 'xxx' or
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write update query and use where clause to find rows containing "xxx" in those columns. If you have multiple columns then add it to Where clause like below. I dont know table structure so i just post random code and you modify as per your table structure

```
Update table set UPDATE_FLAG = true Where columnA = 'xxx' or columnB = 'xxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the above answers will do the trick with some modification for your particular table structure. I would suggest that you run a SELECT first with your criteria and check that it returns the correct rows BEFORE running the update if you are not confident in your SQL skills.

```
SELECT *
FROM {table}
Where {c1} = "xxx"
Or {c2} = "xxx"
.....
```